# Can we construct a sequence of trigonometric polynomials that converges pointwise to a given continuous function on the torus?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

Consider any continuous function $f$ on an $m$-dimensional Torus $\mathbb{T}^m$. Can we construct a sequence of band limited functions (trigonometric polynomials), with the band width (degree of the trigonometric polynomial) along any direction, being non decreasing, in such a way that the sequence converges pointwise to the function $f$?

Comment: Refined and posted another question here, which adds computability condition, after reading the answer by Yuval. https://mathoverflow.net/q/362189/14414

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multidimensional Fejer series, i.e the Cesaro averages of the Fourier series of f, will converge uniformly to f.  See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1789.pdf or https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X12000546 for a lot more detailed information.

Comment: That would be a different question. The paper you cite involves computability from finite samples. Rather than editing your question when it is answered, it is better to post a new question.